# Metapost suffix to string

Tags: metapost

Is there a way to convert *suffix* to *string*?
More specifically, i need to do something like this:

```
def myMacro (suffix a, b) =
    something.a = fOne(a);
    something.b = fOne(b);
    something.scantokens("somethingelse"&**suffixtostring**(a)&**suffixtostring**(b)) = fTwo(a,b);
enddef;
```

Comment: that's what `str` does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
def your_macro(suffix a, b) = 
  something.a = 42;
  something.b = 64;
  something.scantokens("prefix" & str a & str b & "suffix") = 94;
enddef;

your_macro(p,q);

show something.prefixpqsuffix;
% shows 94

end.
```

If you want to assign some value of a non-numeric type to `something` you should declare it appropriately before trying to assign to it.  For example, `pair something[];` or `string something[];`.  But beware that if you do this the suffixes must be valid *numeric* values, because a collective subscript declared with `[]` can only be numeric.

You also might want to think about the scope of the `something` variables.

Comment: Thank you! It works just fine. Actually, i tried _str_ (as it was the only operator that looked appropriate to me in mpman), but i wrote it with brackets (_str(a)_) and it didn't work.